# javascript object filter based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following object and I want to filter it based on some properties and output only some parts of it.

```
{
    "email" : "john.doe@acme.com",
    "name" : " John Doe",
    "groups" : [
        {
            "name" : "group1",
            "country": "US",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c2", "address" : "some address 2" },
                { "localId" : "c3", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "group2",
            "country": "Canada",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c3", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the result should look like:

```
{
    "email" : "john.doe@acme.com",
    "name" : " John Doe",
    "groups" : [
        {
            "name" : "group1",
            "country": "US",
            "contacts" : [
                {
                  "localId" : "c3", 
                  "address" : "some address 3" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So my conditions are:

```
groups.name="group1"
groups.contacts.localId="c3"
```

how can I achieve it using some ecma6 js function? with the least memory load? I am in nodejs env **>=8.9.0**.

### update:

here is my failing attempt:

```
const conditions = {"groups.name": "group1", "groups.contacts.localId": "c3"};
let res = mylist.map((i)=>{
  return {
      email: i.email,
      name: i.name,
      groupsName: conditions.groups.name
  }

})
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is to help you fix your code

Comment: @charlietfl please see the updated question wit my failing attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly succinctly with `filter()`. If you filter on group name first you won't waste time filtering the contacts:

```js
let obj = {
  "email": "john.doe@acme.com",
  "name": " John Doe",
  "groups": [{
      "name": "group1",
      "country": "US",
      "contacts": [{
          "localId": "c1",
          "address": "some address 1"
        },
        {
          "localId": "c2",
          "address": "some address 2"
        },
        {
          "localId": "c3",
          "address": "some address 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "group2",
      "country": "Canada",
      "contacts": [{
          "localId": "c1",
          "address": "some address 1"
        },
        {
          "localId": "c3",
          "address": "some address 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let newObj = {
  "email": obj.email,
  "name": obj.name,
  "groups": obj.groups.filter(item => item.name == "group1").map(g => (g.contacts = g.contacts.filter(c => c.localId == "c3"), g))
}
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: what is the `comma g` at the end of the filter/map line?

Comment: Hi @Bonnard, that's the comma operator. It makes g the return value of the map. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `map`. If `obj` is your initial object then you can do:

```
obj.groups = obj.groups.filter((g)=>g.name==="group1")
for(int i = 0; i < obj.groups.length;i++)
{
    obj.groups[i].contacts = obj.groups[i].contacts.filter((c)=>c.localId==="c3"))
}
```